# S3 plot.list for a list of new class objects

Tags: r

I am writing a package for data analysis. The main analysis function, foo_fit() for example, creates an object with class "foo".

I have already made a new method for plotting the foo object with plot.foo(), however I now want to be able to pass multiple foo objects as a list/vector to plot and have a new method to handle more than one foo object being passed.

Does anyone have insight into if making a function like "plot.list()" would be a bad idea.

Ideally the function would understand that a list was passed, and then check the classes of each object of the list.

The concern I have with making a function like "plot.list" is that the method would be called for any list object, regardless if it was "foo" or "hclust" or "data.frame" etc.

## Update

So working on my local drive I have noticed something.
`foo` is a list in itself. For this example lets say its a list of three such that when you call `names(foo1)` it returns "data", "parameters", "residuals".  thus passing `plot(x = c(foo1, foo2))` x is now a list of 6. Thus to get my desired result, I will always need to pass objects in the following format `plot(x = list(foo1,foo2))`. Which isn't the end of the world, but a bit irritating.

I'm in the process of making a general `plot.list()` and share it here when finished.

Comment: Create a "foolist" class?

Comment: Or include a check for the content of the list in your plot.list method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make `foo` a vectored class (see `?person` for something similar).
2. Provide a function `plot_list_elements(x)` that just loops through a list `x` and plots the contents.
3. Make a new class `foo_list` that holds multiple `foo` objects. Then you can write `plot.foo_list(...)` or any other kind of method you'd like to vectorize (see `Polygons` in the `sp` package for something similar).
4. Leave it up to the user to write `for (x in my_list) plot(x)`, which isn't so bad.

Comment: This is the general idea in a way, however the method for foo_list will be different